# UISplitView – multitask, navigationItem's titleView missing after resizing

Tags: ios, splitview

I am having a very weird problem for iPad's multi-tasking resizing. This is how i set up my titleView:

```
navigationItem.titleView = theView
```

And I resize the SplitView in iPad multi-tasking so I can have two apps running side by side. After a few size changing, my titleview is missing from the UI.

Debugging it from the log, it is still in the navigationItem's titleview hierarchy but just not showing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same issue and have yet to find a resolution.  When using the `title` property it works great, but using `titleView` the view will disappear at times when changing sizes when multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following seems to have fixed my issue:

Assuming the view you want to place as the title view on the navigation item is declared as self.titleView:

[self.titleView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44.0].active = true;

Hope that helps anyone else looking for the same thing.

I found this via this article:

[Custom title view as large title in iOS 11 new navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45043946/)